# dealing with many decimal points in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiplication

Im currently getting this result for multiplication

```
(0.01317818 * 0.00014300) 
=> 1.88447974e-06
```

How can I make the returned result

```
(0.01317818 * 0.00014300) 
=> 0.00000188
```

Across the whole system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 8 decimal places:

```
"%.8f" % (0.01317818 * 0.00014300)
=> 0.00000188
```

A bit simpler than using big decimal.

Comment: this is perfect, is there a way to tell my model that all the numbers will have this formatting?

Comment: Not that I know of  but you can make a column for your model of the decimal type. In that column you can give options to specify scale and precision . `add_column :yourmodel, :number, :decimal, scale: 8`    To reference Rails guides: "precision Defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing the total number of digits in the number.
scale Defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the number of digits after the decimal point"

Comment: that would be great, but Im using PORO to connect to a 3rd party API, so there is no fields here

Comment: Are you just trying to format the numbers when accessing them as attributes, or do you need them rounded after each mathematical operation (with the risk of losing accuracy)?

Comment: @Phil I just need them to be formatted, Im dealing with currency so I cant afford to round and lose value

Comment: My suggestion would be to use attribute 'getters' that simply do `def name; "%.8f" % @name; end`. But if you are worried about accuracy to 8 decimal places, I might consider carefully whether floating point types are what you should be using. Floating point arithmetic can be inexact. Consider BigDecimal as suggested in another answer or RubyMoney https://github.com/Rubymoney/money. Or test thoroughly with known values and results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bigdecimal`. It is a `gem`.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

a = BigDecimal.new('0.01317818')
b = BigDecimal.new('0.00014300')
c = a * b
```